Resample volumetric image data in Python
I have volumetric data representing 3D scans of human breasts, with voxel sizes of (0.2mm, 0.073mm, 0.47mm). I need to resample this data so that all voxel sizes are the same. Is there a Python function available for resampling with interpolation?
Alternatively, I'm looking to write a custom function that achieves the following:
volume, mask, label = dataset[0]

def resample_volume(volume, pixel_sizes={'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.073, 'z': 0.475}):
    # Implementation goes here
    return resampled_volume


scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator

Actually i want to know how to use it

I've found that there are two options to go with:

scipy.ndimage.zoom:

def resample(x, pixel_sizes = {'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.073, 'z': 0.475674}):

    # Determine the smallest pixel size
    smallest_pixel_size = min(pixel_sizes.values())
    # Calculate the scaling factors
    scaling_factors = {dim: pixel_sizes[dim] / smallest_pixel_size for dim in pixel_sizes}
    # Resample the dataset using zoom function from scipy
    return zoom(x, zoom=[scaling_factors['x'], scaling_factors['y'], scaling_factors['z']], mode='nearest')


scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator:

def resample_volume(volume, pixel_sizes={'x': 0.2, 'y': 0.073, 'z': 0.475}):
    steps = list(pixel_sizes.values())    # original step sizes
    x, y, z = [steps[k] * np.arange(volume.shape[k]) for k in range(3)]  # original grid
    f = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), volume)    # interpolator
    step = min(steps)
    dx, dy, dz = [step for i in range(3)]   # new step sizes
    new_grid = np.mgrid[0:x[-1]:dx, 0:y[-1]:dy, 0:z[-1]:dz]   # new grid
    new_grid = np.moveaxis(new_grid, (0, 1, 2, 3), (3, 0, 1, 2))  # reorder axes for evaluation
    return f(new_grid)

The second method yields unsatisfactory results for image masks. The images below illustrate the outcomes obtained using zoom and RegularGridInterpolator, respectively:


Now, The question is, is there any better solution available?
